# How to call a method from a different class in a java project

Tags: java

How do I call a method from a different class in a java project? I have two different classes, each are in the same java project. The name of the first class is Applications, while the name of the second class in ShowChar. These classes are each in the same java project. What I must do is obtain a string input from the user, then I must obtain an integer from the user, then I must tell the user what letter lies on the integer they chose. I did all of that. That is what the class ShowChar does, but what I am supposed to do is call a method from the ShowChar class in the Applications class. I can not get this to work. Please help.

Here is my ShowChar class-

```
public class ShowChar {


char showChar(String text, int index)
{
    char letter='0';

    if((text.equals(null)))
    {
    System.out.print("Invalid input string. The process"
                          + "terminates");
    }
    else{ 
        if(index<0 || index>=text.length())
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid input for index\n"
                           + "The first character of the text is " + text.charAt(0));
            return letter;
        }
    else{
        if(index>=0 && index<text.length()) 
        {
        System.out.println("The character you asked for is: " + text.charAt(index));
        return letter;
        }
    }
    }

return letter;
}
}`
```

Here is what I have gotten figure out with my Applications class-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);




    String text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the text: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the index: ");
    int index= keyboard.nextInt();

    ShowChar sc = new ShowChar();




    System.out.println("character found: " + sc.showChar(text, index) );



}
```

}

Down at the bottom I am supposed to print to the console the letter that I found, but i cant seem to get it  to work. Whenever I run my program with any input the System.out.println statement always comes back with "character found: 0" I must be missing something

Comment: Also in showChar method text.equals(null).... change this to null check.                                                                 text != null

Answer (score 1):

A method of a class can be called using the object name and the method name separated by dot(`.`), as mentioned here:

```
objName.methodName(params);
```

And you are calling it correctly in your sysout:

```
sc.showChar(text, index)
```

You are simply missing to concatenate "character found:" string with the output of showChar method using `+` operatror in 
your sysout

```
 System.out.println("character found: "+ sc.showChar(text, index) );
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Add cancat operator `+` at following line

```
 System.out.println("character found: "+sc.showChar(text, index) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you doing exactly that ?

```
ShowChar sc = new ShowChar(); // object of ShowCar class




    System.out.println("character found: " + sc.showChar(text, index) ); // calling a method of ShowCar class
```

Comment: i put exactly what u put in the the println statement and it did not work, my java program told me there was an error

Comment: You missed the `+` sign for concatenation. =)

Comment: I am sorry, I have never been taught about concatenation, what is it exactly?

Comment: concatenation is when you add strings together to produce new strings.  for instance "hello" + " world" would produce the string "hello world"

Comment: Concatenation simply means joining two Strings together to create another String. @BlackPanther Thanks for helping me out here =)

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, but I am still a little confused, how would I "concatenate" my strings in my program? Sorry, I am new to this stuff

Comment: @user2924444 Either by using `+` or by using `concat()` method of a `String` object.

Comment: @user2924444: your method `sc.showChar(text, index)` returns a string and you are concatenating it with the string "character found: " using the `+` operator to pass to the `println` method like this 
`"character found: " + sc.showChar(text, index)`. which part of this are you not understanding?

Comment: so you guys are saying I should concatenate my "character found: " String? And to concatenate it I would just add a + in between teh strings?

Comment: sorry, was overthinking what you guys were saying. I concatenated it, but when I run the program the console prints this out: The character you asked for is: s
character found: 0

Comment: I need to have it print the letter, not the number